# Creating a variable with a function in R

Tags: r, function, variables

I want to regress the following equation:
     x5  = B0 + B1(x1-x2) + B2 * max[0,(x2 - x1)] + e

I have some trouble with generating the max[0,(x0 - x1)] variable. 
The variable should either be 0 if (x2-x1) is <0, or the difference between (x2-x1) if >=0.

```
 d1 <- structure(list(Date=c("2012-01-01", "2012-06-01",
                 "2013-01-01", "2013-06-01", "2014-01-01", "2014-06-01"),
                 x1=c(10, 12, 17L, 29L, 27L, 10L), 
                 x2=c(30L, 19L, 22L, 20L, 11L,24L), 
                 x3=c(28, 23L, 22L, 27L, 21L, 26L),
                 x4=c(30L, 28L, 23L,24L, 10L, 17L), 
                 x5=c(14, 17, 19, 16L, 30L, 26L)),
                 row.names=c(NA, 6L), class="data.frame")
 rownames(d1) <- d1[, "Date"]   
 d1 <- d1[,-1]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
pmax(0, d1$x2 - d1$x1)
#[1] 20  7  5  0  0 14
```

This returns maximum between `x2 - x1` or 0.

`ifelse` approach would be

```
ifelse(d1$x2 - d1$x1 < 0, 0, d1$x2 - d1$x1)
#[1] 20  7  5  0  0 14
```

Comment: A third option for fun: `with(d1, (x2 - x1) * ((x2 - x1) > 0))`